# A program that takes in a matrix and outputs the fastest path to the "exit" and the number it takes to get there

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

So I'm having a lot of trouble understanding c++ again I've taken my programming class twice and failed. I need help. I'm not interested in programming anymore because it's obviously not for me. I just need to pass. Here's the problem:

***The goal of this assignment is to practice recursive algorithms by writing a program that takes in a matrix representing the number of guards in each room of the castle and outputs the fastest path to the princess and the number of guards you will have to fight.***

You're moving through a map(array) that looks like:

```
5 5
6  2  3 44 15
1  7  2  9 10
11  1  5 14 12
5 17  2  1 20
21  7 33  4 25
```

Where the first to numbers are the size of your array and you can only move right and down. 
So an output would be:

```
50 > > v v v > v >
```

We're given a skeleton which we have to fill in but I don't know what some of it does and it might be too long to copy and paste here, I'm new to the community. 
How would you tackle this assignment

Comment: two words: dynamic programming

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion you try to simplify the problem. So take a step right, compute the score for this step and add it to the rest of the solution by calling the same function on a smaller matrix (leaving out the left column). Then take a step down and do the same with the smaller matrix leaving out the top row. Then choose the solution with the lowest score.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a dynamic programming problem.
I don't know how to pass a 2-d array as a function parameter.

Someone correct me please(How to pass 'matrix' array and 'result' array as function parameters). Rest all part is fine
Algorithm is simple. Just start from the last position and come backwards.
where result[i][j] = min(result[i+1][j],result[i][j+1])

```
void function(int a,int b,int** matrix,int** result){
if(result[a+1][b] == -1 && result[a][b+1] == -1){
    result[a][b] = min(function(a+1,b,matrix,result),function(a,b+1,matrix,result));
}

else if(result[a+1][b] == -1 && result[a][b+1] != -1){
    result[a][b] = min(function(a+1,b,matrix,result),result[a][b+1]);
}

else if(result[a+1][b] != -1 && result[a][b+1] == -1){
    result[a][b] = min(result[a+1][b],function(a,b+1,matrix,result));
}
return;

}

int main(){
    int p,q;
    cin>>p>>q;
    int matrix[p][q];
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++){
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    int result[p][q];
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++){
            result[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    result[p-1][q-1] = matrix[p-1][q-1];

    for(int i=q-2;i>=0;i++){
        result[p-1][i] = matrix[p-1][i] + result[p-1][i+1];
    }

    for(int i=p-2;i>=0;i++){
        result[i][q-1] = matrix[i][q-1] + result[i+1][q-1];
    }

    function(0,0,matrix,result);

    cout<<results[0][0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what your code is doing? I'm slightly confused. You set up 2 matrices, one has the value {1,2,3,4,5,....} the other {-1,-1,-1,-1...} then what?

Comment: result[i][j] stores the shortest path value from ith row jth column to the last position.
So we just need result[0][0]. So I initialized result array with '-1' . Then fill the result array starting from the last position